# anybody know of a left-right symmetric keyboard?

Tags: keyboard

in the standard keyboard the homerow and the bottom row are offeset horizontally by about half key size. so they are symmetrical for left and right hands. but the home row and toprow are offset horizontally by about a quarter key size. so they become asymmetrical for the left and right hand positons when fingers extend to the top row
i guess it is a relic from the heredity.

is there a keyboard available without this asymmetry?

Comment: A good question, but on the wrong site.

Comment: Programmers need peripherals too `:)`

Comment: howto migrate this to the correct site.  maybe programmers.se?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check this:
http://www.trulyergonomic.com/
I think this keyboard really uses the symmetry idea in a good way. It will be released soon, though.
About the offset, the reason is there come from long ago, with the mechanical type-machines...
No serious reason any longer, but people just get used to that.

Comment: now only if it comes with dvorak keycap layout. :)
exactly what i had in mind. 
i was frustrated with almost everyone replicating the old designs.

Answer (score 4):

There are some nifty symmetric keyboards under the "Solutions" section [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120610065639/http://xahlee.org/emacs/keyboard_problems.html).  From the same author, [here is a list](https://web.archive.org/web/20120610065551/http://xahlee.org/emacs/ergonomic_keyboards.html) (with illustrations!) of some other attempts at symmetric keyboards, some of which have no offset whatsoever.

Comment: Excellent link "(with illustrations!)", the best collection of keyboard photos I've ever seen. And I've looked a lot. :)

Answer (score 4):

Have you seen the [typematrix](http://www.typematrix.com/) keyboard?

[image: typematrix keyboard]

I believe that I've seen the layout you describe referred to as "stacked" because the keys are stacked on top of one another, rather than offset. Apparently this company calls it a "matrix" design. They also have little images showing the difference:

> **Staggered Columns**
>   Forces unbalanced motions that strain fingers, hands, and wrists.
>   [image: Staggered Columns]
>   **Vertical Columns**
>   Reduces motions that cause repetitive strain injury (RSI).
>   [image: Vertical Columns]

Why you'd ever willingly use anything other than a Model M is beyond me, however. :-)

Comment: i did not mean one without offsets,  just one with offsets equal for both hands.  but it does sastisfy the symmetry criteria. :) 
+1 for the pics.

Answer (score 3):

Many keyboards without the offset are available, here's several from one company: http://www.chestercreektech.com/keyboards.html

I've tried typing on keyboards without the offset, and it is *hard*. You might be surprised.

Some keyboards are very very different: http://www.frogpad.com/

I'd like to try one, but am under no illusions that I could ever get used to it.

Comment: I don't think that..... oh god, the link just opened up and I'm going to die now. Anyways, I don't think that the asker wants *no* offset, but rather that the offset be symmetrical on both halves of the main area.

Comment: No kidding, I somehow think "teaching" children to type on such a strange layout would be counter-productive: when kids graduate to a real keyboard, it'll feel all wrong. Or, they'll always hate the layout without an offset because it never feels right. (The offsets are there for a reason. :)

Comment: @Ignacio: that is exactly what i meant.

Comment: those are somethings i didnt know of, though that was not exactly what i meant. :)

Comment: @sarnold Yes the offset are there most likely so the mechanical levers could fit nicely. I'm not saying that a pure columnar layout is best, but let's not pretend every detail about the keyboard i well thought out from a modern perspective...

Comment: @olejorgenb, I've since bought a Kinesis Ergo Advanced keyboard; it aligns the keys in two key wells, with strict columns. It took one week before I could type at all, and roughly a month before I felt rough parity with traditional keyboards.